# Stale blocks on Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

from https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/07/11/toward-a-12-second-block-time/

```
At a block time of 600 seconds, as in Bitcoin, this is not an issue; 12 seconds is a very 
small amount of time, and Decker and Wattenhofer estimate the total stale rate as being 
around 1.7%. Hence, an attacker does not actually need 50.001% of the network in order 
to launch a 51% attack; if the attacker is a single node, they would only need 
0.983 / 1 + 0.983 = 49.5%. We can estimate this via a mathematical formula: if transit 
time is 12 seconds, then after a block is produced the network will be producing stales 
for 12 seconds before the block propagates, so we can assume an average of 12 / 600 = 0.02
stales per valid block or a stale rate of 1.97%. At 60 seconds per block, however, 
we get 12 / 60 = 0.2 stales per valid block or a stale rate of 16.67%. At 12 seconds
 per block, we get 12 / 12 = 1 stale per valid block, or a stale rate of 50%. Thus, 
we can see the network get substantially weaker against attacks.
```

I couldnt understand the concept of stale blocks..
so if the transit time is 12 seconds (a block reaches to every node in the network) and the block time is 600 seconds ( New block will only be appended in 600 seconds) how come the rate of stale block is 12/600 = 0.02, because the block will only be made in 600 seconds and then it will take another 12 second to reach every node.

Answer (score 0):

A stale block is a valid block that is not part of the main chain, for example when another block at the same height was mined previously.

The 12/600 is the probability of a stale block. If it takes 600 seconds to produce a block and 12 seconds propagating it. Then during those 12 seconds miners might be producing a stale block.